# Macro for calling a series of macro-generated functions with similar names (i.e. f_0, f_1, f_2, ...)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I got stuck with quite peculiar problem, and I at the moment have no idea how to solve it.

I am using the following block of macros to generate functions with similar names:

```
#define CONCAT_IMPLEMENTATION(arg1, arg2) arg1 ## arg2
#define CONCAT(arg1, arg2) CONCAT_IMPLEMENTATION(arg1, arg2)

#define UNIQUE_FUNCTION_NAME(index) CONCAT(f_, index)

#define GENERATE_FUNCTION() void UNIQUE_FUNCTION_NAME(__COUNTER__) ()
```

So code like this:

```
GENERATE_FUNCTION()
{
    std::cout << "first function" << std::endl;
}

GENERATE_FUNCTION()
{
    std::cout << "second function" << std::endl;
}
```

is replaced with:

```
void f_0 ()
{
    std::cout << "first function" << std::endl;
}

void f_1 ()
{
    std::cout << "second function" << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any way to implement a macro or a function that would call all the generated functions?
That is to say it would call functions from **f_0** to **f_N**, where **N** is a current value of `__COUNTER__` macro.
Something like that:

```
#define RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS() // ??? //

int main()
{
    RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS();
    return 0;
}
```

Looks rather impossible up to me. Could you give me any suggestions, please?

Comment: What is the real problem are you trying to solve? No, not the one about calling functions this way. But the problem to which you believe the solution is to generate functions like that, and then call them.

Comment: When you have to ask a question about a hard solution, detail what the solution is supposed to solve. More often than not  you'll find you're asking a question about the wrong problem and should have asked about the problem above it. Colloquially this is called [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Does it all have to be done with macros?  You could store pointers to your functions in a vector and then walk through that to call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic in preprocessor. To overload, you have to enumerate all possible cases anyway.

```
#define RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_1()  UNIQUE_FUNCTION_NAME(0)();
#define RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_2()  RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_1()UNIQUE_FUNCTION_NAME(1)();
#define RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_3()  RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_2()UNIQUE_FUNCTION_NAME(2)();
#define RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_4()  RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_3()UNIQUE_FUNCTION_NAME(3)();
#define RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS()  do{ CONCAT(RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_, __COUNTER__)() }while(0)

int main() {
    RUN_ALL_GENERATED_FUNCTIONS();
   //  do{ f_0();f_1(); }while(0);
}
```

Note that `__COUNTER__` is non-portable, you might as well use descriptive function names (and readability of the code is important and `__func__` will expand to something meaningful) and put pointers to these functions into a custom linker section with `__attribute__`, then iterate over that section to execute all functions. It's typical to do that - within testing frameworks and in kernel, with `.init` and `.fini` etc. sections.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for macros here, just push function pointers into a vector then you can iterate through the vector calling each function in turn. One possible implementation would be:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Functions
{
    static std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions;

    template <typename T>
    static T make_function(T f)
    {
        functions.push_back(f);
        return f;
    }

    static void call()
    {
        for (auto& f : functions)
        {
            f();
        }
    }
};
std::vector<std::function<void()>> Functions::functions;

auto f_1 = Functions::make_function([]
{
    std::cout << "first function" << std::endl;
});

auto f_2 = Functions::make_function([]
{
    std::cout << "second function" << std::endl;
});

int main()
{
    f_1();
    f_2();
    Functions::call();
}
```

If you really need to you could still wrap `Functions::make_function` into a macro.